# how to plot a 4d array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'd like to plot 4 arrays in a 4d shape

```
x = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
z = [0.18702222222222223, 0.09351111111111111, 0.062340740740740745, 0.04675555555555556, 0.03740444444444445, 0.031170370370370373, 0.02671746031746032, 0.02337777777777778, 0.02078024691358025, 0.018702222222222224]
c = [0.9468, 0.4734, 0.31560000000000005, 0.2367, 0.18936000000000003, 0.15780000000000002, 0.13525714285714288, 0.11835, 0.1052, 0.09468000000000001]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
img = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c, cmap=plt.hot())
fig.colorbar(img)

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot does not correspond to the values that I have. Moreover, I really don't want to user scatter format, I need to have a shape for the plot but this is the only code that worked. Is there any other suggestion to improve my code?

i would like to have something like this

[image]

Comment: You have only 10 values for `z` (and for `c`). So you can only draw a curve (or 10 scattered points) in 3D. For a surface you'd need a `z` and a `c` for each combination of `x` and `y`.

Comment: I need to have 20 scattered point not 10 having 10 value in x and 10values in y. It's like combining x with z and y with c in one plot

Comment: You: _"It's like combining x with z and y with c in one plot"_ ፨ Me: ? — seriously, could you try to explain a little better what you have and what you want to do?  I know that what you've written makes sense, makes perfectly sense to you but…

Comment: in other words z=f(x) and c=f(y) that's why i need to have 20 points not just 10, each value in the arrays x and y has its value in z and c respectively. for example (2, 0.18702222222222223) and (2, 0.9468)